# Rearrangeable matrix visualization

Tags: matrices, bipartite-graphs

Let $M$ be a matrix of $n$ rows and $m$ columns having values only $0$ or $1$. $M$ is said to be rearrangeable if you can swap (interchange) some columns or some rows with each other in a way such that all the primary diagonal elements are $1$. I know this can be solved using bipartite matching but I am unable to visualize its solution. 
Link to original problem - [Link](https://csacademy.com/contest/round-66/task/flipping-matrix/)
Link to a solution - Problem 6 of this [PDF](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~hatami/comp360-F2015/files/hw1sol.pdf)

I am interested to know why we can model this problem as a bipartite matching problem. Since here we can swap two rows and two columns so how can that swap operation(interchange operation) be represented as edges in the graphs and why maximum matching of a certain value guarantees that there exists an answer.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm which takes a given matrix of the specified form, and returns a rearranged matrix with ones on the main diagonal?

Comment: No.  I am actually solving an algorithmic problem I came across a contest few days ago.

Comment: Can you post the actual example?

Comment: Hi I have updated the statement above.

Comment: Note: In the linked version of the problem, $m=n$ (i.e., the matrices are square).

Comment: So, you're asking us how you can visualize bipartite matching?

Comment: No i am asking how we can visualize this problem in form of a bipartite matching.

Comment: There's a bipartite graph where the vertices in one part are the rows of the matrix and the vertices in the other part are the columns. There's an edge joining vertex $r_i$ to vertex $c_j$ if there's a 1 in row $i$, column $j$. A bipartite matching in this graph is a rearrangement of the matrix so the diagonal is all ones. Oh, and if you want to ensure that I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson this is the same explanation as per the solution manual above. Can you elaborate how we can convert a swap operation to the edges of bipartite graph. I want to know the intuition or the explanation behind the logic that you just stated. Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what a swap operation is. If you want someone to answer your question, you have to make it clear in the body of your question just exactly what your question is. This is the information I have been trying to draw from you, with little success. Don't give us links to problems and solutions offsite – write out, in the body of your question, exactly what it is you want to know.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time. I have updated the statement a bit. I hope its more clear now @GerryMyerson